# The problem is conversion from string to type date is not valid

Tags: vb.net

```
Option Explicit On
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1
    Dim objCon As New OleDbConnection
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strConnect As String = "Provider= Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Abry\Documents\Bilik.accdb"
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    Private Sub TempahButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TempahButton.Click
        Dim startDate As String = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
        Dim str As String
        startDate = DateTimePicker1.Value

        objCon.ConnectionString = strConnect
        objCon.Open()
        str = "Insert into bilik(Bilik, Tujuan, [Masa Masuk], [Masa Keluar]) values(?, ?, ?, ?)"
        str = "Insert into bilik(Tarikh) values(startDate = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString)"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, objCon)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Bilik", CType(BilikComboBox.SelectedIndex, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Tujuan", CType(TujuanTextBox.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Tarikh", CType(DateTimePicker1.Value, Date)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Masa Masuk", CType(MasaMasukMaskedTextBox.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Masa Keluar", CType(MasaKeluarMaskedTextBox.Text, String)))

        Try
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            objCon.Close()
            TujuanTextBox.Clear()
            BilikComboBox.Text = ""
            DateTimePicker1.Value = ""
            MasaMasukMaskedTextBox.Clear()
            MasaKeluarMaskedTextBox.Clear()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Tarikh is date declare

Conversion from string to type date is not valid

Comment: First of all, thanks for not telling us where in the code that the error occurred.  It sure was fun wading through all that code, which is nonsensical in parts, and trying to work out what line might have generated that error.  Now that the fun is over, it turns out that everything you posted other than the one line that generates the error is completely irrelevant.  Thanks again.

Comment: The code is rather nonsensical in parts, even ignoring the specific issue you're asking about.  You declare `strDate` and then assign two different values to it, then never use it.  You also assign two different values to `str`, only the second of which gets used when only the first of which actually makes sense.

Comment: Because the value of DateTimePicker1.Value is Date Type, so I think you don't need to convert it's type to Date, try to change CType(DateTimePicker1.Value, Date) to only DateTimePicker1.Value. And I look in your code, you fill str twice, which one will be executed?  And the last, you can't store any data to date picker except date value.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, apparently, here:

```
DateTimePicker1.Value = ""
```

That means that everything else you posted is irrelevant.  The issue is, as the error message clearly states, it is not valid to assign an empty `String` to a property that is type `Date`.

The `Value` property of a `DateTimePicker` is type `Date` and so you must assign a `Date` value to it.  There's no such thing as an empty `Date` so you must either assign a default date, e.g. today's date:

```
DateTimePicker1.Value = Date.Today
```

or you need to use the functionality built into the `DateTimePicker` control to indicate that no date is selected.  If you want to know how a `DateTimePicker` control works, read the class documentation.